# Using HTML UI in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am using the shiny package in R and the ask is to trigger a piece of code when the user hits submit button.It works well when i create the interface using UI.R however when using an html as the UI the code does'nt get triggered, I believe this is because the HTML doesn't treat the button as an action button.

I have defined the class name for the button as class="btn btn-default action-button but still no luck.

I have gone to the extent of copying the html generated by UI.R as the source code for html but still the issue persist.

Comment: Can you include your code here?